# PhoneGap - Invalid App on Market

Tags: android, cordova, package, google-play

I've made an webbapp with jQuery Mobile and through PhoneGap converted it to an Android app. It works fine in the simulator and in debug mode.

But when I upload it to market (after signing it) I just get "Invalid Package" (I think this is the right translation) when I try to install it...

I have no idea how to go on with it now and fix the problem... tips are very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried completely removing the app from your phone, and re-installing. Sounds silly, but if you have the app on your phone signed with the debug key, it's not possible to install the app signed with the release key

Comment: What Entreco says is correct - if you have the debug version on your phone already then you need to uninstall it first. This also applies if you have the release version on your phone and you want to install a new debug version to test.

Comment: @Entreco: You shouldn't answer the question in a comment. Put it in an answer so that Tibbelit can accept it if it is correct. Even if it is wrong in this case, it is a very useful answer for others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try completely uninstalling/removing the app from your phone and re-installing the new signed version. If you previously signed app with the debug key on your phone, you cannot install the same app signed with another key on your phone. And vice versa

Comment: Thanks fo the answer! 
But this is not the problem. I've uninstalled the application before downloading (and installing) it from Market. I've also tried to install the application to other devieces which never had the app installed before...